# Duplicate entries in the array created with PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I have a problem where a duplicate array is created within my MVC architecture. I have literally commented out everything and reviewed the code as best I could but cant seem to find the problem. I do suspect I know where the problem is but not sure how to fix it (see comment in code under `Model()`)

**Directory Structure**

[image]

**Part Of `Controller()`**

Below is part of controller containg `login()` method

```
class Home extends Controller{
 public function login(){
        $this->model('register');
        // I put the below in brackets (create assosiative array) and assign it key users since we would like to access the array for later to loop on and manipulate
        $this->view('home\login', isset($_REQUEST['submitbtn'])? ['users' => $this->model->loginUser('john@gmail.com', 'John')] : false); //hard-coded values for quick testing
        $this->view->render();
    }
}
```

**Part Of Model `Register()`**

```
class register extends DB
{
    private $db;
    //protected $userInfo = [];

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = DB::getInstance();    
    }
        public function loginUser($email, $pword)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email AND pword = :pwd";
        $stmnt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $stmnt->bindValue(':email', $email);
        $stmnt->bindValue(':pwd', $pword);
        $stmnt->execute();
        if ($stmnt->rowCount() > 0) {
            return  $stmnt->fetchAll(); //I suspect the "duplicate array" problem is here
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Part of View `login.php`**

```
<form action="" method="post" style="border:1px solid #ccc">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Sign Up</h1>
        <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
        <hr>

        <label for="name"><b>Full Name</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Fullname" name="fullname" id="fullname" required>

        <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="email" name="email">
        <label for="pwd"><b>Password</b></label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="pwd" id="pwd" required>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember" style="margin-bottom:15px"> Remember me
        </label>

        <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="#" style="color:dodgerblue">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>

        <div class="clearfix">
            <button type="submit" name="submitbtn" class="signupbtn">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submitbtn'])){
    if(array_key_exists('users', $this->view_data )){ //$this->view_data comes from View class & contains data passed to view
        echo 'array key exists';
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($this->view_data);
        echo '</pre>';
        #TODO fix double array problem
        /*foreach ($this->view_data['users'] as  $user){
            echo '<br />';
            echo 'This is the $USER'. $user;
            echo '<br />';
        }*/
    }
}
```

**PROBLEM & Question**

Notice the duplicate array which is created, my question is why and where is this created? Am I right if I say I suspect it comes from `return $stmnt->fetchAll()` if so how do I work around it?

```
Array
(
    [users] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [userID] => 2
                    [0] => 2
                    [email] => john@gmail.com
                    [1] => john@gmail.com
                    [pword] => John
                    [2] => John
                    [firstname] => John
                    [3] => John
                    [lastname] => Kruger
                    [4] => Kruger
                    [balance] => 
                    [5] => 
                    [phone] => 48484848
                    [6] => 48484848
                    [country] => ZA
                    [7] => ZA
                    [join_date] => 2018-04-24 22:23:36
                    [8] => 2018-04-24 22:23:36
                    [modify_date] => 2018-04-24 22:23:36
                    [9] => 2018-04-24 22:23:36
                    [ip_address] => 127.458.14
                    [10] => 127.458.14
                )

        )

)
```

**Further Info `View()` class**

```
class View
{
    protected $view_file; //represents where file is
    protected $view_data; //data you want to pass

    public function __construct($view_file, $view_data)
    {
        $this->view_file = $view_file; //equal to view_file you are receiving
        $this->view_data = $view_data;  //equal to view_data you are receiving
    }

    public function render()
    {
        //if file exists we will go to the view() method which was set in homeController()
        // we are creating the path inside the home inside the view so if file exists only thing we need to do is:
        //include the file
        if (file_exists(VIEW . $this->view_file . '.php')) {
            include VIEW . $this->view_file . '.php';
        }
    }
```

Any help / advice or constructive criticism appreciated. Please note this is still very much a work in progress, also, I am learning MVC design architecture and am still a "rookie" so to speak.

Comment: try with `$stmnt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Comment: Thanks let me give it a go real quick

Comment: @AkintundeOlawale thanks for your help!

Comment: This has **nothing** to do with MVC

Comment: @tereško why do you say that? this is from an MVC course I bought on udemy...?? Im trying to replicate and modify some of the techniques I learned in the course. The name of the course was "Introduction to PHP MVC" maybe cause I didn't show full source code?

Comment: Then you have been scammed. The  code you have shown is filled with bad practices, indicates security flaws in your password storage and violates *separation of concerns* (which is the core principle of mvc). Your question itself is about PDO, and the code shown does not contain even the most basic understanding of mvc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default return from `fetchAll()` is to return an array containing elements indexed by the column name and the position (PDO::FETCH_BOTH), if you just want them with names use

```
return  $stmnt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

The return types are documented in `fetch()` - http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php, which uses the same types as `fetchAll()`.

You can set the default mode for all statements for a connection using...

```
$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Worked liked a charm THANK YOU so much!, I will accept when time expires

Comment: Would you mind if I ask you one more question which is semi-related to question posted...

Comment: Don't mind, although if it's too different it may be easier to ask a new question.

Comment: IN the `login()` method under `Home Controller()` class I use

`$this->view('home\login', isset($_REQUEST['submitbtn'])` what can I do so that the `isset()` is not reliant on the name of Submit Button? i.e if the front end dev changes submit btn name the code wont work...what is the best work around to this? Sorry If im taking advantage of your knowledge here....Hope it makes sense

Comment: It's a bit different from the current problem.  But how would you deal with the designer changing all of the field names?  Could be worth a new question as front end isn't my speciality - sorry.

Comment: NO worries many thanks for the help